# modifying stopwords in R's TM package

Tags: r, text-mining, stop-words, tm

I have a problem modifying the english.dat stopword file from R's TM package.
Anything I add to it is unrecognized. I tried adding at the beginning of the file, the middle, the end, still nothing works. Only the original text of the file is recognized.
I tried saving the file as ASCI, UTF, UTF-8, to no avail.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: same question with this [adding stopword in mn package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446408/adding-stopwords-in-r-tm)

Comment: as i mentioned in another response, that is impractical if you have a large file of stop words to add

Comment: Please explain how this is impractical.  What format are the additional words in?  `c` works with many vectors so if you use it and your additional words are in a vector it does the job and this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @animalcroc as Rinker said you can load your stopword to the vector, like this => load your stopwords to the `mystopwords` varibale and then `myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),mystopwords))`

Comment: I have a list of perhaps 3000 words in a text file... The issue I'm facing here must be a bug in R. Very strange that the TM package can't read text I type in.

Comment: it was easier than i thought to do this. I simply used R's scan() function to read my stopwords file into a vector, which I then concatenated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding them this way, as a concatenation to the "english" list:

```
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'), "available", "via") to add words
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)
```

Comment: thanks, but I have a large list of words to add and this would be impractical

Comment: it was easier than i thought to do this. I simply used R's scan() function to read my stopwords file into a vector, which I then concatenated