# removeWords not working

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to build a wordcloud of the jeopardy dataset found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/1uyd0t/200000_jeopardy_questions_in_a_json_file/

My code is as follows:

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(wordcloud)

jeopQ <- read.csv('JEOPARDY_CSV.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

jeopCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(jeopQ$Question))
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, removePunctuation)
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, removeWords, c('the', 'this', stopwords('english')))
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, stemDocument)

wordcloud(jeopCorpus, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE)
```

The words 'the' and 'this' are still appearing in the wordcloud. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: for what it worth the and this are already in `stopwords('english')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you didn't perform a lower case action. A lot of questions start with "The". The stopwords are all in lower case, e.g. "the" and "this". Since "The" != "the", "The" it is not removed from the corpus

If you use the code below it should work correctly:

```
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, removePunctuation)
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
jeopCorpus <- tm_map(jeopCorpus, stemDocument)

wordcloud(jeopCorpus, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think that the line with `removePunctuation` should be placed *after* `removeWords, stopwords("en")`. If you look at `stopwords("en")`, there are many words with apostrophes, like "didn't", "we'll", "he'd" which would not be recognized if the punctuation was removed before attempting to remove these words.

Answer (score 0):

The construction of argument does not seem right:see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446408/adding-stopwords-in-r-tm) and [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/removeWords)

```
tm_map(jeopCorpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),"the","this"))
```

But as said, those words are already included, so simply

```
tm_map(jeopCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
```

should work

Comment: I have already tried both of those and it didn't work. Do you think it has something to do with the version? When I type out stopwords() to see all the stop words, I don't see 'the' and 'this' in the list. What am I missing?

Comment: I think that the answer of @phiver leads to the right solution. I believe it still contains a little mistake concerning the placement of `removePunctuation` that I mentioned in a comment, but apart from that it should work. The essential point is that you must transform the text to lower case using `content_transformer(tolower))` *before* removing the stopwords. The words "the" and "this" are in the list of `stopwords("en")`, but only in lower case, and not with a capital "T" as they may occur at the beginning of sentences.